# Why can't I connect to a site on my local network with WP7 via Wifi?

Tags: windows-phone-7, networking

I am working on a WP7 application that retrieves data from a web service.  The web service was written by a co-worker and is hosted on a server connected to the office network.  The app works just fine in the emulator.  However, when I run the app on the actual phone (HTC Surround) it can't connect to the web service.  If I try to open a website hosted on the same server that doesn't work either.  However I can connect to other websites just fine.

One thing to note is - I don't have a SIM card in the phone, so the only available data connection is via WiFi, which connects to the office network (the same network that the service is hosted on).

I'm able to hit this website just fine from my laptop (on the wired office network), via an Android phone using WiFi, and via an Android phone using 4G.

What could be going on here?  Alternatively - how can I debug this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Does opening some static page hosted on that server open in the browser on the device? Can it hit any other sites on the interwebs?

Comment: No and Yes - see the last two sentences of the first paragraph.

Comment: My first guess would be name resolution on your lan. Have you tried hitting the service by IP address?

Comment: I can get to the IP address.  However the site in question is not the default site in IIS (the same server hosts about 20 sites), so just using the IP address isn't going to work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd start debugging it by using [Connectify.me](http://www.connectify.me/download-lite/) (or something similar) to re-broadcast the wifi network you're having problems with, start [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) up and analyze what happens when the device's browser connects to some external site vs the site hosted on your network.

Comment: Connectify.me is the winner.  If I connect the phone to that WiFi, everything works great.  I'll accept this answer unless I hear an actual explanation from somebody about what the problem is.